# Need Help: VS 2005 Properties Changing

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2005, properties

I am working in Visual Studio 2005. I have multiple splitters on the screen. I have set the splitters IsFixed and I have also set fixed panel sizes. In addition to this I have locked the control. For some reason, when I switch into debug mode the splitter distance value is changing entirely on its own. These changes do not take place with any consistency, the vary in distance changed. Other components, which are also locked, are moving all on their own as well.

Anyone with similar experience? Any ideas?

Comment: Which technology are you using? WinForms? WPF?
Or are you talking about the Visual Studio application itself?

Answer (score 1):

The settings will stick to either mode you are in. But sometimes plugins or parts of VS does mess it up  :(

I recall seeing a plugin written to save 'views', but when I tried it, it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't tell you what is causing this.  The way that the windows forms splitter works is through the Docking property.  There should be no need to lock the controls.  All of the controls on the form should be docked.  (Including the splitter)

For example, if you want to split vertically, you have your first panel docked left.  Then the splitter (Orientation set to vertical) is also docked to the left.  The second panel is docked to fill.  The width of the first panel (which is docked left) will determine the location of the splitter.  It should not change now.

The z-order is important here for layout purposes.  If you want a more detailed look of how the controls are laid on on your form, open the Document Outline.  This will list the controls in a tree, and you can see where they are in the z-order.